# Problem with Clarity Design in feature modules

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm kind of struggling with building my Angular App in combination with the Clarity Design Framework. I followed the getting started guide (https://clarity.design/get-started/developing/angular/), and the elements itself are working correctly. The problem comes in when I start to break down the html structure into multiple components.

I started to build the **app.component.html** like following:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <header class="header-1">
        <div class="branding">
          <a href="/" class="nav-link">
            <clr-icon shape="shield-check"></clr-icon>
            <span class="title">test</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </header>    
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-area">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The header section works fine, but the sidenav (clr-vertical-nav from Clarity) doesn't look like it's [supposed](https://clarity.design/images/angular-components/vertical-nav/jigglypuff.png) to: [how it actually look's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lETQ.png)

The sidenav component is sitting in a feature module, as stated in the documentation I imported BrowserAnimationsModule and ClarityModule in the root module and in the feature module.

**sidenav-component.html:**

```
<clr-vertical-nav>
  <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./charmander" routerLinkActive="active">Charmander</a>
  <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./jigglypuff" routerLinkActive="active">Jigglypuff</a>
  <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./pikachu" routerLinkActive="active">Pikachu</a>
  <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./raichu" routerLinkActive="active">Raichu</a>
  <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./snorlax" routerLinkActive="active">Snorlax</a>
  <a clrVerticalNavLink routerLink="./credit" routerLinkActive="active">Credit</a>
</clr-vertical-nav>
```

However, when I place the content of sidenav-component.html directly in the app.component.html everything works like it is supposed to. Can anyone explain me why or how I can solve this problem?

**Edit**: simple project on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-2bav14?file=app/app.component.html)

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try moving the `app-sidenav` element above the `.content-area` div?
e.g:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <header class="header-1">
        <div class="branding">
          <a href="/" class="nav-link">
            <clr-icon shape="shield-check"></clr-icon>
            <span class="title">test</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </header>    
    <div class="content-container">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
        <div class="content-area">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, spin up a simple example that reproduced the issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team) with one of the starters so I can look at a working apoplication.

---------EDIT---------

It does work. Move the app-sidenav above the content area and handle the height of the clr-vertical-nav with css on the application side.

Here is the css I chose to write, ymmv:

```
clr-vertical-nav {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-67112199?file=app/core/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.css) is a forked stackblitz demonstrating a working sidenav.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work - it aligns the sidenav to the left, but still not full height and the elements are not clickable. See the project on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-2bav14?)

Comment: I updated my answer. In short, it does work but you have to handle the height of the vertical nav component on the application side. When it was written a design choice was made not to have it expand vertically to fill its container. Changing that now would be a breaking change so we have to live with it and manage the height on the app side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please don't get me wrong, I appreciate it and it helps, I'm just curious and want to learn, that's why I'm asking again - when you see my example and uncomment in the app.component.html the nav is placed correctly and with correct height? So why is it different when I move the same code out into a different module?